# How to convert JSON to BSON document in Erlang?

Tags: json, mongodb, erlang, bson

I am writing a  web back-end ( in Erlang/Webmachine)  that receives  json from client java script. I am using  MongoDB  as database.

How to convert the JSON string received from client to BSON document suitable to 
mongodb driver and reverse ?  Is there any library available for  this  ?

Answer (score 2):

The MongoDB Erlang driver implements the [bson-erlang](https://github.com/mongodb/bson-erlang) project.  This project should have everything to meet your needs.